# call cherrypy function after session expiration

Tags: session, cherrypy

I have cherrypy server. It is working with files and I need to delete files when session expires. Is it possible call cherrypy function, when session is expired?

Answer (score 0):

You could **write your own session class that inherits from the already existing session class** and overwrite the expiring method.

You can take a look at

http://github.com/3kwa/cherrys

it is not what you want but this guy has written a session class to use redis (a key/value storage) for sessions. And he uses the method I mentioned to overwrite methods with the desired behaviour. You may want to look into "cherrypy/lib/sessions.py" for an overview of session methods and classes.

It's not the most convenient solution, though.